# How to get a list containing strings to represent certain values as an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I hoped I phrased this correctly, I'm new to python and coding in general. I have two sets of two lists which are evenly populated. The list represents the individuals in the family and the second are their ages.

```
adams = ['ben', 'susan', 'billy']
adamsage = [40, 38, 14]

smith = ['brooke', 'john', 'trent', 'sam']
smithage = [45, 46, 16, 15]
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can add the individuals in the family together for instance:

```
ben + susan + billy = 82
```

I also want to be able to add different combinations such as just parents or just kids:

```
brooke + john + ben + susan = ...
```

There's also no overlapping names so I don't have to worry about duplicates. I've tried:

```
adams = adamsage
print(int(float('ben')) + (int(float('susan')))
```

But I get a value error. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: don't use multiple lists but a list of objects (Person), you will get problems later on if you keep using multiple list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  Welcome to the site.  Good question....  You'll need to learn a bit about data structures here.  You have 2 ways to go on this.  The second below is better, but both could work...

So you have 2 lists that have a relationship by index.  As a general plan you could:

- look up the index of the name in the first list
- use that same index value to get the age out of the second list
- repeat that for the names of interest and keep a running sum

You could do the above with a loop using the `index()` function to find the index of the name.

Your alternative is to move the data into a different data structure that establishes a pairing of name : age, or what is called a key : value relationship.  In python, that is a dictionary.  You could then look up the age by name in the dictionary inside of a loop and keep a running total.  This is the better plan.

Is that enough to go on?  Are you familiar with dictionaries and basic loop structure?  If you are stuck, comment back and I or someone else can show how to do the basic steps of either of these approaches!

Comment: Ok sweet! Thanks so much, I have heard of dictionaries, but have never used them. I began researching them and can see how beneficial they are. Thanks again for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) for this, would look something like:

```
adams = {
    'ben': 40,
    'susan': 38,
    'billy': 14
}

smith = {
    'brooke': 46,
    'jhon': 45,
    'trent': 16,
    'sam': 15
}

print(adams['ben'] + smith['brooke'])
```